# Create a Read-only and Write-only user in Couchdb 2.1 Cluster

Tags: couchdb

I recently created a 3 server couchdb 2.1 cluster and was looking into creating some application security.  The idea is to have a write-only user that will be given to applications that need to write to the database and a read-only user that will be used by applications that read from the database.  Another read-only user will be given to developers to do what developers do.  The problem is that I can't find any documentation on doing this.  We had this previously on an old 1.6 installation, but that was set up before my time.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a readonly user is fairly straight forward.  You have to create a validate function on the database that only allows certain roles to write to the database.  The old stack overflow article is here.  [CouchDB-wide read-only access rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713437/couchdb-wide-read-only-access-rights)

Write-only databases are a bit trickier.  You have to put a proxy in front of the database that only allows access to the write interfaces and blocks access to read interfaces.  I had a project where we accomplished this by putting a proxy in front and pointing it to a rewrite interface on couchdb.

Proxy points to

> https://couchserver.com/databasename/_design/app/_rewrite

The design doc looks like

```
{
   "_id": "_design/app",
   "rewrites": [
       {
           "to": "../../_bulk_docs",
           "from": "/db/_bulk_docs",
           "method": "POST"
       },
       {
           "to": "../../_revs_diff",
           "from": "/db/_revs_diff",
           "method": "POST"
       },
       {
           "to": "../../_local/*",
           "from": "/db/_local/*",
           "method": "GET"
       },
       {
           "to": "../../_local/*",
           "from": "/db/_local/*",
           "method": "POST"
       },
       {
           "to": "../../_local/*",
           "from": "/db/_local/*",
           "method": "PUT"
       },
       {
           "to": "../../../",
           "from": "/",
           "method": "GET"
       },
       {
           "to": "../../fakedb",
           "from": "/",
           "method": "GET"
       },
       {
           "to": "/../../fakedb",
           "from": "/db/*",
           "method": "GET"
       }
   ]
}
```

This allowed us to open the minimal interfaces to let pouchdb do a one way sync of data from the client to our server.  The last bit we had to add was a workaround for pouchdb that creating errors because it makes a request to

> https://proxyserver.com/db

when starting replication.  The call isn't really necessary and the workaround was to create a document in the database that returned a similar response.

```
{
   "_id": "fakedb",
   "_rev": "1-063ad938e0501105d2f304db16dd4970",
   "db_name": "dbname"
}
```